# How do I update the domain variable of the CHttpRequest with the redirected domain/url in c++

Tags: c++, redirect

I have the following code in a cpp program I have been asked to update with new urls:
The customer facing url doesnt change but the redirect may so I need to get the program to go to the customer facing url and automatically follow the redirect and download the file, but I get the unable to connect error connection cannot be established error code 12005

```
CHttpRequest httpRequest(DOWNLOAD_DOMAIN, DOWNLOAD_URL, MINIMUM_NORMAL_DOWNLOAD_SIZE);
```

but the url redirects to another address and this is not being passed so the download fails.

```
CHttpRequest::CHttpRequest(const std::wstring& domain, const std::wstring& url, const unsigned int minCorrectSize):

    m_url(url),
    m_data(NULL),
    m_dataSize(0),  
    m_session(NULL),
    m_fileSize(0),
    m_connect(NULL),
    m_request(NULL),
    m_domain(domain),   
    m_reportedSize(0),
    m_hProgressBar(NULL),
    m_minCorrectSize(minCorrectSize)
{
}
```

How do I update the domain variable of the CHttpRequest with the redirected url.

example of the url is --  https://domainname/Download/File/4
the ChttpRequest gives a 302 redirect to a hosted site.
https://abcde.blob.core.windows.net/downloads/domainname/filename.zip
the redirect

Comment: If you get a result code in the 300-range (redirects) create a new request object with the new location and perform the new request. Continue in a loop until there's no longer any redirects, or there's too many.

Comment: There is only one redirect but it doesn't go to the same domain.

If I use the redirected domain and url it works but I can't do that as the redirect may change, and we don't want to have to go thru this all over again as it requires users to get a new version of the download program, and if we can get the redirect working then as long as the customer facing url doesn't change we don't need to update theprogram

Comment: Add some generic code to handle all kinds of redirects, then you won't have to update the code for other redirects later. For example (pseudo-code) `unsigned attempts; std::string url = the_original_url; for (attempts = 0; attempts < 10; ++attempts) { CHttpRequest request(url, ...); /* Do request */ if (IsRedirect(result_code)) { url = get_location_from_http_response_header(); } else { /* Either an error or Okay */ break; }`